# Why wont typescript recognize the colors npm package?

Tags: typescript, colors, compiler-errors

Really easy question, in node js I can do something like this:

```js
import 'colors';
console.log('Im blue (ba da bo de ba bo di)'.cyan.bold.underline);
```

Which will print blue colored text to the console.
However, this same code will not run in typescript, because of the error:

```
Error: Property 'cyan' does not exist on type 'Im blue...'
```

I installed the colors types package, installed the node types package, and tried "", '', and ``, none of which worked.

I know I can just force typescript to ignore the error, but what is the 'correct' way to fix this issue?

Comment: There is no need to install types package because `colors` has types definitions inside itself.

Comment: The latest version of `colors` and TS 4.0.3 are incompatible while using `bold`. Any other props are fine.